# Embedding a custom field from one post to another

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a WordPress post with a custom field (text area).

Is there a way to get data from that custom field to display in another new post on the same blog via a code embed or some shortcode?

Example: 
Post A has a custom field that contained a gallery of 3 pictures. I want this gallery of pictures to be embeddable into another new Post B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation.

Add to functions.php:

```
// add hook for new shortcode
add_shortcode( 'custom_field', 'shortcode_field' );

function shortcode_field( $atts ) {
    // get attributes that were passed in the shortcode
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => null,
    ), $atts ) );

    // if we don't at least have a field name, then exit
    if ( ! isset( $atts[0] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // field is the first attribute
    $field = esc_attr( $atts[0] );

    // get the current post
    global $post;

    // if no post id was passed as a parameter to the shortcode, use the current post
    $post_id = ( null === $post_id ) ? $post->ID : $post_id;

    // do the custom field lookup for the appropriate post and retur the text
    return get_post_meta( $post_id, $field, true );
}
```

You would use the shortcode in the wordpress editor in either of the following two ways:

```
[custom_field "field_name"] - looks up field_name for the current post
[custom_field "field_name" post_id=999] - looks up field_name for post with id 999
```

You can get fancy and use the same concept with some gui shortcode generator plugins such as [Shortcodes Pro](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-pro/), which will give you a nice shortcode button in your wordpress editor.